# ThreadPoolExecutor and RejectedExecutionExceptionHandler

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, java.util.concurrent

I want to use a bounded queue for a `ThreadPoolExecutor` but I want to use my custom `RejectedExecutionExceptionHandler`. I would need to do that so that I can put rejected tasks to a separate queue and after a while try to resubmit them.
Is a custom `RejectedExecutionExceptionHandler` the solution to my problem? If yes how do I implement one?
Or else what would be the best way to deal with my issue?

Comment: What puts you off using an unbounded queue instead?

Comment: @DuncanJones:To make sure I don't overload the server

Comment: You won't overload the server, as you'll still have to define a maximum number of threads. I'll stop posting here as you are having the same discussion with Peter in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an unbounded queue as this will queue tasks which cannot be run for later use.  I would sue Executors.newFixedThreadPool in your case.  You may be interested in what this does

```
public static ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads) {
    return new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads,
                                  0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                  new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
}
```

Note: it uses an unbounded queue.

IMHO the simplest/best way to deal with the problem is to run the task in the current thread.

This ensures all tasks are performed in a timely manner using the current thread where there is no spare background threads.

```
new RejectedExecutionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
        r.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: This will ignore tasks if the pool is shutdown, but you could use that instead.

Comment: This seems reasonable but I think it would slow down my server.Why not use a separate queue?Wait a while and resubmit them?

Comment: It will only happen when your server is overloaded in any case (assuming you have an optimal number of threads in your pool)

Comment: The only other option is to use an unbounded queue, which is basically what you are implementing in a round about way.

Comment: When you say unbounded queue how is this configured? Just to be sure we are talking about the same thing

Comment: A LinkedBlockingQueue is used by default. Currently, any task will be executed by the pool immediately if it can or added to the queue to be executed later if a thread is not free.  How is what you are proposing different to this?

Comment: I had in mind that there is the limit of maxPoolSize.As a result a task submitted and we exceed the maxPoolSize is rejected.So you are saying it will be rejected if I do `new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(100)` for example (in the constructor of `ThreadPoolExecutor`) but if I do `new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()` instead I have an unbounded queue?

Comment: Correct, it won't be rejected, it will just be queued. BTW: This is what `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n)` uses.  If you have a CPU bound task, you might not want to have more threads than you have cores.

Comment: What if I want an upper bound on the tasks but not to call the rest in the caller's thread. Just store them in a second queue and after a while try to place them in the execution pool again.I didn't understand why is this a bad approach.

Comment: So you will have two queues with a total of N tasks instead of one queue with a total of N tasks except the two queues will have some tasks completing long after they were added. Instead of asking why you shouldn't do it, you should be asking; what is the *very good reason* you have to make it more complicated than it would otherwise be.

Comment: The `0L` in time parameter effectively kill all extra threads as soon as they are idle. Right?

Answer (score 2):

In your case you would want to choose a *saturation policy* which comes to play only when the bounded queue gets filled up . The saturation policy for a thread pool executor can be modified by calling `setRejectedExecutionHandler()` method .  There are four types of saturation policy :

1. Abort ( this actually throws an exception and lets the caller deal with it )
2. Discard( this actually discards the newly submitted task)
3. Discard - oldest ( this discards the task that was to run next and tries to resubmit the new task)
4. Caller-runs policy which implements some form of throttling that neither discards tasks nor throws an exception , but instead tries to slow down the flow of new tasks by pushing some of the work back to the caller . So the caller thread becomes busy running new tasks and thus can not accept any more tasks during that time .

For your situation I think `CallerRunsPolicy()` makes most sense . Do this :

```
executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
```